# Django flatpages The empty path didn't match any of these

Tags: django

On the administration page, I set the URL for the Django flat pages to "/", which is expected to be displayed as the home page at http://127.0.0.1:8000/. Doing so I encountered an error:

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in core.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    admin/
    <path:url>
The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

But if I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000// with double slash then the home page is displayed correctly. My only urls.py file looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib.flatpages import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += [
    path('<path:url>', views.flatpage),
]
```

And I took all the code completely from [the official guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/flatpages/#using-the-urlconf). How to display the django flatpage homepage at http://127.0.0.1:8000/?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the django.urls.path method Django offers the django.urls.re_path method. The path method is designed to perform matches against exact strings, whereas the re_path method is designed to perform matches against patterned strings based on regular expressions. In my case it’s enough to fix it this way:

```
urlpatterns += [
    re_path(r'^(?P<url>.*)$', views.flatpage),
]
```

As a result, we get the correct processing of requests at http://127.0.0.1:8000/. More details about using path, re_path methods can be found at the [link](https://www.webforefront.com/django/regexpdjangourls.html).